# Interrupting a Runnable with a method of the class

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

How can I write a method of a class implementing the `Runnable` interface (started from an `ExecutorService`) that would interrupt the thread?

I know that I can use `Future fut = es.submit(foo);` (where `es` is the `ExecutorService` and `foo` is an instance of my class) and then call `fut.cancel(true);` from inside the main function of the application, but how do I call something like that from inside the class itself?

I would like to have in my Runnable class a method

```
public void stop() {…}
```

so that I can call `foo.stop()` from anywhere (including from the main function of the application) and it will work as if I had used the `Future.cancel` function (it has to raise ÌnterruptedException` if the thread is awaiting to acquire a Semaphore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do - implementing a `stop()` method inside a `Runnable` - may actually introduce some confusion in the structure of your code. Why? A `Runnable` object is, by design, something which holds the code that has to run. But adding a `stop()` method would go beyond the sole responsibility of a `Runnable` object: that is, you will make it able to control the execution of your code. That should be avoided.

Here is a hint: there is no `start()` method in `Runnable`. Indeed, there is one in the `Thread` class, and the `Runnable` interface has been introduced in the JDK to reduce coupling between the "runnable" code and the object which *controls* its execution (an instance of `Thread`).

My question is: why aren't you satisified with the `future.cancel()`? Could you please add some precisions in your design requirements?

Comment: I understand your explanation as to why it's not good to have a Runnable that stops itself. I prefer to use a Runnable and start it from an ExecutorService because that way I have threads that were started from a same object, and the ExecutorService can shut them down when needed (and also control the number of such threads started at the same time). I ended up writing a stop method that was passed the Future as argument from the main class. It worked and was more or less what I wanted, but it might not have been a proper use of Runnables.

Answer (score 3):

```
            public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

                private Thread currentThread;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                    // Do here something interruptible
                }

                public void interrupt() {
                    if (currentThread != null)
                        currentThread.interrupt();
                }
            }
```

But as it has been said, it's bad architecture since you're mixing responsibilities of WHAT is being done (Runnable) with HOW it's being done (execution)

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class the implements `Runnable` and also another interface:

```
public interface StoppableRunnable extends Runnable {
    public void stop();
}
```

And use this type of `Runnable` which is guaranteed to have a `stop()` method which you can call.

Example of use:

```
public MyRunnable implements StoppableRunnable {

    private volatile boolean stopped = false;

    public void run() {
       while(!stopped) { // Do something.... }
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem since it wouldn't send an interruption to the Runnable. In my main loop, the thread is mostly stuck waiting on Semaphores, so I need the stop method to make it stop waiting and raise an exception in order to go back to the start of the loop and seeing that it has been stopped.